# Errors in using SVMlight on visual studio

Tags: svm

I am using svmlight for using it with HOG descriptor. I downloaded the hog program from [here](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG). I am using the latest version of SVMlight.

I am getting the following errors in `svmlight.h`:

```
'WORD' : ambiguous symbol                           
cannot convert from 'svmlight::WORD' to 'WORD'
left of '.wnum' must have class/struct/union        
left of '.weight' must have class/struct/union      
cannot open source file "svm_common.h"
cannot open source file "svm_learn.h"                       
"WORD" is ambiguous
```

I really don't know how to solve this issue as this a library?

Comment: Animesh, do you finally manage to use the svmlight.h? I have got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem,

What I did is, change WORD in svmlight.h to svmlight::word
and that solved the problem.

but then it gave me some linking errors.

So, then I create a lib file using svmlight header and c files and include it.

(I used visual studio 2010)